# Magento 2 System Configurations not showing

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, system.xml, system-config

I am trying to bring some system configurations for my custom module in the backend. I wrote the following code for the configurations but I am not getting any results.

> Tm/Productpoll/etc/acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
<acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                    <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                        <resource id="Tm_Productpoll::config" title="Productpoll Section" sortOrder="50" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

> Tm/Productpoll/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="productpoll" translate="label" sortOrder="300">
        <label>Product Poll</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="productpollsettings" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Product Poll Settings</label>
        <tab>productpoll</tab>
        <resource>Tm_Productpoll::config</resource>
        <group id="general_settings" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>General Settings</label>
            <field id="enable_disable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Enable</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
</config>
```

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

**acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">              
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">                 
                        <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                            <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                                <resource id="Tm_Productpoll::config_productpoll" title="Productpoll Section" />
                            </resource>
                        </resource>
                    </resource>                 
            </resource>
        </resources>        
    </acl>
</config>
```

system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">

<system>
    <tab id="productpoll" translate="label" sortOrder="300">
        <label>Product Poll</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="productpollsettings" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Product Poll Settings</label>
        <tab>productpoll</tab>
        <resource>Tm_Productpoll::config_productpoll</resource>
        <group id="general_settings" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>General Settings</label>
            <field id="enable_disable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Enable</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
</config>
```

Comment: no use, I'm not getting any results

Answer (score -2):

On your `system.xml` instead of

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
```

Use

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
```

Below is example of both

**acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Custom_Module::banner" title="eTrade" sortOrder="100" >
                    <resource id="Custom_Module::configuration" title="Configuration" sortOrder="1000" />
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="sampletab" translate="label" sortOrder="1">
            <label>Test</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="banner" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Banner</label>
            <tab>tab</tab>
            <resource>Custom_Module::configuration</resource>
            <group id="settings" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="1" translate="label">
                <label>General Settings</label>
                <field id="enable_module" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
                    <label>Enable Module</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Afer that run

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I'm not getting any results.

Comment: Hi @jackson5 Follow this https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html